# Rails 4 Strong Parameters Unknown Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I've followed the Railscast for migrating an application to Rails 4 and the transition to Strong Parameters. http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4

I have my Create/New methods working fine. But, I'm having problems when I try to update a record. I keep getting the following message:

ArgumentError in CustomersController#update
Unknown key: first_name

I've looked at various posts here on Stack Overflow and also generated a new Rails 4 app to verify that I'm doing things correctly. I'm obviously missing something.

Here is my Controller code for the update method:

```
def update
    @customer = Customer.find(customer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.update(customer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is where I'm setting up my strong parameters:

```
private

def set_customer
      @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
end

def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :middle_initial, :last_name, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :phone, :gender, :email, :membership_id, :date_of_birth)
end
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to use `customer_params` in your `find` statement, you'll want to use the normal `find(params[:id])` for that.

Strong Parameters are only used when creating/updating database records.  They effectively replace the Rails 3 `attr_accessible` calls in your models.